# Active Sandbox, moving target, good idea? Don't be silly

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A few times that I've wanted to give advice in comments on main regarding the way to approach questions, I've wanted to refer the users to try using the sandbox as a way to develop their approach to achieve an acceptable standard.

So far - so good.

I've included a link in my comment to the sandbox (what I thought at the time was the sandbox, a short while later turned out to be inactive). I'm not convinced that it was not my error. I'm concerned that inactive links may confuse new users.

Need I expand on the confusion of consequences to not only the questioner in those threads, but subsequent readers? Particularly those unfamiliar with the site. They sure as heck confuse me, and I'm not new.

I'm aware that every thread of sandbox name has a forward link to the next valid one, in my view this is not enough.

I'd request (again) a magic link to the sandbox, however I've read the (impenetrable to a non programmer, and from what I can gather to programmers also - essentially a stonewall) answer to the previous itterations of the question here - consider: [Is there a "magic link" to the Sandbox? Should there be?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6092/is-there-a-magic-link-to-the-sandbox-should-there-be)

But this seems to offer a solution, except I don't understand it: [Add magic link for MCVE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240260/add-magic-link-for-mcve)

## Question: Could an explanation please be published in somewhere that doesn't disappear into the shadows over time as to how to find (and create links to) the (active) sandbox?

**All viable solutions welcome.**

- By viable I mean have a decent chance of being implemented by the powers that be.
- Solution means: enabling users to instantly find the active sandbox without confusion or having to click on several sequential links with lots of reading.
- Welcome means: doesn't require programming skilz for the membership to impliment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about linking to the [Sandbox FAQ](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/639/28)?  Because it's a meta post, the community can and apparently does update it when the sandbox moves.

Years ago Stack Exchange made (limited) durable URLs available to sites; for example, http://s.tk/miyodeya points to Mi Yodeya's publications page.  Unfortunately, [SE discontinued this service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301751/162102), so we can't get a perma-URL from them.  In light of that, the best bet seems to be a durable meta post.  It's an extra step to get to the actual sandbox, true, but either way somebody coming in is going to have to read some documentation, and the FAQ provides that.

Comment: Good answer, I feel that I should have stumbled upon it before now somehow. Then again maybe I did, and ignored it on the basis of not realising it was being updated - can't say. Favourited though. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Agrajag this is the best answer you're going to get.  Magic links can only be created by Stack Exchange, and the odds of getting SE to create a sandbox magic link are, frankly, zero.  The FAQ is a hair out of date and probably should separate the "why" explanation from the "how," which is more completely presented at the sandbox itself.  But it's as close as we're going to get to a permanent sandbox link.  A complete list of sandbox links is included at the sandbox (see the "Maintenance" section).